Cut command failing
We have a ksh Script that is suppose to give the output as last day of the month but when ever we run it we get the below error:
cut: fields are numbered from 1
Try ‘cut —help’ for more information,

I have been trying to debug this but unable to do so.
Here is the code:
#!/usr/bin/ksh

if (( $(#) <= 1 )) ; then print "${0##*/} <two-digit month> <four-digit year›" ; exit 101 ; fi 
 typeset -Z2 month=${1}
 typeset -Z4 year=${2}

typeset -i whencecal=$(whence cal 2>/dev/null | wc - l)
if (( whencecal != 1 )) ; then print "FATAL: \"cal\" command not found!" ; exit 102 ; fi

typeset -i wrdcount=$(cal ${month} ${year} | sed -e "/^$/ d" | tail -1 | wc -w)
typeset -Z2 momaxdate=$(cal ${month} ${year} | sed -e “/^$/ d” -e “s/[ ][ ]*/,/g” | tail -1 | cut -d”,” -f${wrdcount})

print ${momaxdate}

What can be done to fix this

Are you sure that ${wrdcount} is always greater than 0?

@Marco ${wrdcount} is sometimes 1 and most of the times 0. This is not my script and I have been trying to debug it and it’s failing

Well, the error message tries to say that the first field is number 1. So a field number of zero isn't valid.

When it is 0 then cut -d”,” -f${wrdcount} will give you the error. You better test the variable before you do the statement typeset -Z2 momaxdate with the cut command.

cut —help with the em-dash is also suspicious. But that probably indicatrs the text getting broken in transit.

The ${wrdcount} is the reason for this that I understand but I can’t get to the reason why it’s giving the output as 0, when it’s suppose to tail -1 the  cal  of a given month.. if the month ends at 31 then the out put will be 1 and even if it ends at 30 then also it should be 1, get wrap my head around it

If you have access to GNU date, could you use date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) +1 month -1 day" +%d as a one-liner?

cut: fields and positions are numbered from 1 is what the GNU coreutils version of cut complains if you give it a field number of zero. The fields are numbered from 1, so zero is invalid. (If you gave it something that's not a number, it'd give a different error.)
Now, you know wrdcount ends up a zero, so lets look closer at the output of cal.
$ cal 2 1992 |cat -A
   February 1992      $
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  $
                   1  $
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  $
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  $
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  $
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  $
                      $

Or with od:
$ cal 2 1992 |tail -1 |od -tx1z
0000000 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  >                <
0000020 20 20 20 20 20 20 0a                             >      .<
0000027

That last line is not empty, but contains 22 spaces. Meaning that /^$/ does not match it so it's not removed. You'd need something like /^ *$/, or rather /^[[:space:]]*$/ instead.

Now, all that looks a somewhat convoluted way to get the last day of the month. You could do it with awk a bit more simply:
% cal 2 1992 | awk 'NF > 0 { last = $NF } END {print last}'
29

(NF gives the number of fields on the line, $n is field n, so $NF is the last field and NF > 0 tests if the line has some content, i.e. isn't empty or just whitespace.)
Or, like shown in the comments, with the GNU coreutils version of date:
$ y=1992 m=02
$ date -d "$y-$m-01 +1 month -1 day" +%d
29

(This works because stepping one month forward keeps the day number the same, so it goes to the first day of the next month, from where we can step back to the last of the month of interest.)
